Two neural networks: one for positive input and the other for negative input (tf.cond not applicable)
I want to build a model based on 3 nested neural networks in TF2 as shown in the Image 01.
The input of each sample (for example 1000 samples) is a vector of dimension 13 (2 in the image).
Image 01
The first two neural networks have as output the same variable that is the input of the final neural network. However, I need neural network 1 to activate only when the last value of each sample is positive and neural network 2 to activate when the last value of each sample is negative.
I have tried to do it with tf.cond; However, it cannot perform the operation because it can only receive a scalar in the condition.
Additional information: my model is more complex than this and I need to calculate the model gradients and insert them into the loss function (I'm making a PINNs model).
Thanks in advance!
I have tried to do it with tf.cond; However, it cannot perform the operation because it can only receive a scalar in the condition.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
